# Constructing query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to process filter data in backend and return the person's who matches those filter conditions. The filter conditions be like `((filter A or filter B or filter C) and (filter D or filter E))`
Filter conditions be like "name contains 'name' ". I have scopes for each filter conditions, which is like 
`scope :contains,-> (params){ where('name ilike :name', name: params[:name]}`.

I am planning to construct query with `union` for ORing the filters. I planned to get the result of each filters `User.contains(params)` using to_sql. And combine all the filters with or condition using SQL union and combining the and conditions using active record `merge`.
And execute raw query using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`.

Is there any other better ways to process these kind of filters?